# Hadoop 3.1.0 -- No route to host

Tags: hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 3.1.0 on a cluster of three CentOS 7 machines.  All the machines can ping each other, all machines are configured with SSH. Every firewall port mentioned in the manual is open.  But attempting to run an MR job always results in "No route to host".  Taking down the firewalls on all three machines allows successful MR jobs.  What can cause this?

Comment: Try `traceroute` rather than ping

Comment: Are you sure you're using the Hadoop 3 ports and not the old Hadoop 2/1 ports?

Comment: On way to make sure is run `netstat -tulpn` on each host and make sure you have included all the ports listed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion  cricket_007, traceroute indicates positive connections across all nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions tk421 -- I've done my best to track down all the ports, but have yet to find a complete and definitive list of ports for 3.1.0.

Comment: The actual problem with firewalls is that it doesn't free some ports to connect with the UI and APIs that is why it is recommended to disable iptables/firewalls in a production environment. I suggest you keep your firewall disabled.

Comment: Got all of these ports open -- still no luck!  http://kontext.tech/docs/DataAndBusinessIntelligence/p/default-ports-used-by-hadoop-services-hdfs-mapreduce-yarn